# 404 error while importing stylesheet into ASP.net

Tags: css, asp.net, http-status-code-404

I am trying to import my css file:

[image]

and I am ending up with:

[image]

I dont know what is the problem with css not importing?

Comment: if you are using MVC, use <head>
    <link href="@Url.Content("~/Styles/main.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    @RenderSection("Styles", false)
</head>    OR   USe  @Styles.Render("~/styles/myStylesheet.css")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
@Styles.Render("~/styles/myStylesheet.css")
```

Comment: Can you please add some more info to your answer e.g. where to use the above code etc?

Comment: @Abhinav This is the way how css is referenced in mvc application in safe way